# iOS Send sms message with location object

Tags: ios, xcode, object, text, sms

I've been trying to figure out how to send an SMS message that includes your location. I want it to be the location object similar to when you share your position on the iphone - not just the straight address.
Is there anyway to do this? I've looked at the [reference material](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MFMessageComposeViewController) provided by apple however I don't see any way to add special objects to the body. It looks like you can only add text.

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

SMS is just textual content (Strings) which gets transmitted over carrier airwaves, you can not embed actual objects to the body unless you send an SMS using a format your app can recognise and parse

Stuff like links in messages and addresses and times are sent via plain text and then Apple's Messages app parses it and adds the relevant contextual options (such as hyperlinking so you can open links in Safari and dates in Calendar and Addresses in Maps etc.). There is no way of adding your own contextual formatting options to the stock Messages app

Comment: Thanks, this is a good amount of information. If that is the case, how can I send a message with the correct formatting to send an address to another person. Please see this picture: http://s12.postimage.org/7hd2cr831/image.jpg